# Сколько раз встречается каждое слово в тексте

Tags: java

**Задача :**

В единственной строке записан текст. 
Для каждого слова из данного текста подсчитайте, сколько раз оно встречалось
в этом тексте ранее.
Словом считается последовательность непробельных символов идущих подряд, слова 
разделены одним или большим числом пробелов или символами конца строки.

**Мой ход решения :**

Считываем строку с клавиатуры, определяем сколько слов в строке, создаем массив типа `String`. Длина массива равна количеству слов в строке. В индексы массива сохраняем каждое слово. После сравниваем между собой все элементы и ведем счётчик.

**Мой код :**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Semnadcat1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Введите текст");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = in.nextLine();
        int a = s.split(" ").length;
        int i;
        String[] b = new String[a];
        for (i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            for (String retval : s.split(" ")) {
                b[i] = retval;
                System.out.println(b[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Ошибки:**

Не удается поместить слова в элементы массива.

Comment: `слова разделены одним или большим числом пробелов или символами конца строки` – посмотрите, чему равно `"ааа     ббб".split(" ").length`.

Comment: Эх, парсер пробелы съел. В общем поставьте между словами не один пробел, а больше.

Comment: Посмотрите на свой код(в частности, на вложенный цикл) и подумайте, что вы делаете: на каждой итерации "i" вы присваиваете i-ой ячейке массива "a" разных значений. Одумайтесь. Переписать ваш код можно дюжиной разных способов, но без понимания своего кода не будет толку ни от одного из них.

Comment: @0xFFh ну так подскажите,что нужно подправить,я плохо понимаю многое,направьте в нужное русло(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Метод `split` возвращает массив `String` (слов в данном случае), поэтому нет необходимости вручную добавлять слова в массив.
Для упрощения подсчета количества вхождений каждого слова можно хранить пары "слово - количество" в `HashMap`.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Введите текст");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String string = in.nextLine();
    String[] words = string.split("\\s+");
    HashMap<String, Integer> wordToCount = new HashMap<>();
    for (String word : words)
    {
        if (!wordToCount.containsKey(word))
        {
            wordToCount.put(word, 0);
        }
        wordToCount.put(word, wordToCount.get(word) + 1);
    }
    for (String word : wordToCount.keySet())
    {
        System.out.println(word + " " + wordToCount.get(word));
    }
}
```

Также `split` сделан по "одному или нескольким пробельным символам" с помощью регулярного выражения, что помогает избежать проблем с пустыми словами из-за идущих подряд пробелов.

Comment: Всё прекрасно работает) очень интересный код)

Comment: да скорее, обычный, стандартный

Answer (score 2):

Вариант со стримами:

```
String text = "text hello   text";
String word = "text";

long count = Arrays
            .stream(text.split("\\s+"))
            .filter(word::equals)
            .count();
```